# Stuck on bootloop when I tried to install ubuntu touch on my Galaxy nexus

Tags: ubuntu-touch, galaxy-nexus

I tried to flash ubuntu touch (saucy) on my i9250 and I got stuck on bootloop before I was able to push and flash the last file `saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip`.

Now I am unable to boot into bootloader. When I open my phone it shows the Google logo and then it turns off. The problem is I cannot boot into `bootloader/fastboot` so I can flash the file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you didn't brick it.

[Try booting into System Recovery Mode.](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-access-android-bootloader-or-system-recovery-mode/).

> Press and hold the Volume Down button, and press then Power button until the screen lights up. Then select Recovery and press Power button to confirm.

Might look something like this:

[image: From androidcentral.com's forums]

Comment: I tried this approach but as i mentioned above when i press the volume down and power the google logo appears the unlocked sign and tben it turns off again

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a really late response and you've probably solved it by now, but it may help others too.  I had the same issue with my phone after installing a CyanogenMod rom, where I couldn't even boot into recovery.  You will need to find the stock rom package for your phone on your computer and download the file.  You will also need a way to flash the rom via usb.  For example, a free program called Odin works for Samsung devices.  Regardless of what program you use-- "jumpstart" your phone into download mode:

1. Take off cover and pull out battery
2. Hold volume up + down + power button
3. Plug in usb cable that is connected to the PC (kind of tricky to do)
4. Phone should buzz once, displaying warning triangle that says "No OS installed" or         something like that.  Release buttons.
5. Open the program for flashing the rom, and follow directions specific to that program to flash your stock rom

This is how I recovered my Galaxy S Blaze after soft-bricking it sometime last year. Hope it helps!